# can we have underscore in name for Apps in ipa or apk

Tags: google-play, apk, ipa

I am creating an app, and would appreciate help with naming conventions. I want to use a common file name for both stores. Can someone please help me decide whether it's good pracicpractice to use underscore `_` in the name.

For example, `file_name.apk`  `file_name.ipa`. 
If it causes any issues, I will instead use `filename.extn`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Google Play is concerned, it doesn't matter what filename you give the APK when you upload. Google doesn't store the filename anyway, and it doesn't affect what is given to the user. It is a non-issue.